# cflags '-Wl,-export-dynamic' vs linker flags '-export-dynamic'

Tags: c, cmake, clang

I compiled the same program (not library) with different compilation flags, in CMake with Clang

1. with CMAKE_C_FLAGS = -Wl,-export-dynamic
2. with CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS = -export-dynamic

But I noticed that the second way doesn't seem to work. I can't find the exported symbols. I'm so surprised that only the 1st way works. I don't know if the C compilers do something tricky, or Clang, or CMake. But how to let the second way work? The first way would print a lot of warnings.

Comment: Why would you want to export the symbols from an executable?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Plugins need to call functions from the executable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide same options for second variant.

> set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-export-dynamic")

Because compiler and linker the same in your case.

Comment: for macOS it was `--export-dynamic` (two hyphens)